# ИП Иванова ...оплатила или оплатил?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сказуемые, род

Как правильно прописать в документе?

> ИП Иванова оплатила (оплатил) данный счёт...

В документе прописано полностью: Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова оплатил (а) данный счет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При прямом порядке слов ("Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова оплатила данный счет.") действует следующее правило:

> Сказуемое ставится в форме женского рода, если оно стоит после собственного имени: Автор Н. Петрова предложила редакции увлекательные заметки. Диссертант Иванова изложила интересные наблюдения. ([Автор Петрова, или Названия «неженских» профессий)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)

При обратном порядке слов ("Данный счет оплатил индивидуальный предприниматель Волкова.") действует другое правило:

> Сказуемое в книжно-письменных стилях (особенно в строгой официально-деловой речи) ставится в форме мужского рода....если сказуемое предшествует сочетанию «рассматриваемое слово + собственное имя»: Увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Н. Петрова. ([Автор Петрова, или Названия «неженских» профессий](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89))

Comment: А если Индивидуальный предприниматель написано полностью?

Comment: @Яна В ответе как раз даны два примера, где написано полностью.

Comment: Уточнили информацию...а если предложение построено по-другому.. Данный счет оплатил (а) индивидуальный предприниматель Волкова....

Comment: Я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

**ИП** — *юр. экон. сокр.* от индивидуальный предприниматель.
Аббревиатура, неизменяемая. Используется в качестве существительного мужского рода.

*Как правильно прописать **в документе?***

**В строгой деловой речи** принято формальное согласование, по мужскому роду (безотносительно к полу лица):
ИП Иванова А. А., действующий на основании…
Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова, именуемый в дальнейшем "Заказчик"...

**Но**: если сказуемое находится после собственного имени, то оно ставится в форме женского рода: *Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова оплатила данный счет...*

**В других** формах письменной речи (а не в безликой канцелярской) будет уместен женский род. Например, в газетном тексте:
Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова, обратившаяся в суд с требованием...
ИП Иванова оплатила счет вовремя.

Нет разницы, какую форму Вы используете на письме (полную или краткую) — сочетание все равно имеет мужской род.

[Индивидуальный предприниматель (ИП)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: Где Вы такое нашли: "Индивидуальный предприниматель Иванова оплатил данный счет"?

Comment: Да, сама подзапуталась, спасибо. Жарко!

Comment: Мне кажется, даже в самом "махровом" варианте деловой речи **сказуемое**, стоящее после имени, приобретает форму женского рода. А в определениях и оборотах действительно встречается мужской род.

Comment: Совершенно верно! Я просто слишком увлеклась объяснением про ИП. Ещё раз благодарю. Правку внесла.